# ReactJS: SetState doesn't seem to be firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I have this code in my `app.js` file:

```
componentDidMount() {
     var newData = {...data};
     console.log("New Data: ", newData);

     this.setState({data: newData}), () => {
        console.log("New state: ", this.state.data);
     });
}
```

In the console log I have:

> New Data:  {name: {…}, add: {…}, choice: Array(1)}

However, I do not have the output from `console.log("New state: ", this.state.data);`

If I take the console log out of the '.then()' I get the console output of:

> New state:  []

I am new to react so detailed answers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: may be because 'this' is undefined in ordinary functions as myFunc(){}. And you need to write trough arrow function componentDidMount = () => {}

Comment: @AlexeyNikonov I do not think this is the case. I can `console.log(this.state.data)` and it shows the current state meaning it cant be an issue with `this`

Comment: Try like this. this.setState({data: newData}, () => {console.log("New state:", this.state,data});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you didn't pass correct way of callback. It would be like this:

```
this.setState({data: newData}, () => {
        console.log("New state: ", this.state.data);
 });
```